# Mail has not been sent when sender email-id was yahoo id

Tags: php, email

When I put sender email address other than yahoo id, mail sent and deliver. It also works for yahoo receivers. In script it when I use Gmail as a sender, Yahoo receives but not the vice versa i.e Yahoo sender does not deliver in Gmail.

Is this a server problem or error in my code?

Here is my code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isMail(true);
$mail->IsHTML(true);    
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/logo.png', 'logo');
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/plunder_icon.png', 'icon');
$to = 'nabina.smartmobe@gmail.com'; // receiver email
$mail->AddAddress($to);
$from = 'nvn_shahi@yahoo.com';
$user_name = 'Nabina';
$mail->SetFrom($from,$user_name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($from,$user_name);

$subject = 'Hi';
$msg = 'test';
$mail->Subject    = $subject;
$msg = get_mail_format($msg);
$mail->Body = $msg;
try{
    if($mail->Send()){

        return true;
    }else{

        return false;
    }


} catch(Exception $e){
    //Something went bad
    echo "Fail - " . $mail->ErrorInfo; die;
}
```

Comment: there is no any mails in spam. I had already  checked it.

Comment: Do you receive any delivery notifications failure ? U should set mail/pass for SMTP connection to Yahoo, so the receiver accept it.

Comment: yes. There is delivery failure notification mail in yahoo id.I am not using SMTP mail function . Do I need SMTP ? Can't I send mail simply?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing my answer, as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) says, check the following example and add it to your code:

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
```